# Flutter PWA URL gets truncate in a downloaded PWA (iOS)

Tags: ios, flutter, web, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I have a PWA deployed on Firebase (which has a unique identifier at the end of the URL) that is working in web browsers mobile/web. When I download this PWA (via Add to Home Screen in Safari on iOS) the unique identifier disappears. It's working fine on Mac and Android but doesn't know why the URL gets truncated (on iOS only).

https://localhost:8080/#/brand/71wh212972g (URL in browser while downloading PWA)

https://localhost:8080/#/brand/ (URL in download PWA on iOS)

I'm not sure what to add or remove from manifest.json to make it work for iOS.

Comment: Share your web app manifest.

Comment: @user18309290 Please take a look at my manifest file using this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JNPjDRa42alu3_zvvHpYSmzYFQu6QFrQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

`start_url` is used to define the launch url after the app is added to the home screen.

```
{
...
  "start_url": "https://<your domain>/#/brand/71wh212972g"
...
}
```

> The start_url member is a string that represents the start URL of the web application — the preferred URL that should be loaded when the user launches the web application (e.g., when the user taps on the web application's icon from a device's application menu or homescreen).

See [start_url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url) for details.

Comment: How do I mention the unique id (the one in the end)? Same as the code snippet above?